# Will an AHK script be running on a virtual machine even if i minimize it?

Tags: virtual-machine, autohotkey

I really want to run an ahk script in a windows 10 virtual machine and then minimize the virtual machine so I can use my computer normally while the script is running. I am asking because I do not currently have the virtual machine and I wouldn't like to go through all this procedure just to find out that it is not working. Has anyone from you tried it out? Do I need any software? Do I have to install the machine on a specific VM software?

Comment: Assuming your VM software doesn't come with some sort of stuff that will "put the VM to sleep" when you minimize, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't keep running. I just tried Windows sandbox for you, and it didn't seem to do that at least.

Comment: Ohh, after 5 hours I got it... I run a script, minimized windows 10 virtual Box and the script was running while I was using my computer. So, I have the solution should I delete this post? Someone answer please...

Comment: I didn't see your answer earlier

Comment: You don't *need* to delete it, but it's whatever really. You can also add in the answer yourself down below there. Maybe someone in the future could be searching for an answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

So, yes it works. I tried it on windows 7 64 bit and the script is currently running in the minimized windows 7 virtual Box windows while I am typing this answer. Though, the mouse is not moving when using commands such as MouseMove x, y , click, x, y, etc. (at least for me on windows 7 64 bit) So you have to go to control panel -> hardware and sound -> mouse -> pointer options (on the windows that has opened) -> display pointer trails. Because it is annoying, you can drag the bar to low. Hope it helped :)